# Boundedness requirement Theorem 7.29 Baby Rudin

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> **7.29   Theorem** - Let $\mathscr B $ be the uniform closure of an algebra $\mathscr A$ of bounded functions. Then $\mathscr B$ is a uniformly closed algebra.

An algebra $\mathscr A$ is a family of complex functions defined on a set $E$ which is closed under addition of two functions, multiplication of two functions, and multiplication of a function by a constant.

Definition of uniform closure:

> Let $\mathscr B $ be the set of all functions which are limits of uniformly convergent sequences of members of an algebra $\mathscr A$. Then $\mathscr B $ is called the uniform closure of $\mathscr A$.

Definition of uniform closed:

> If $\mathscr A$ has the property that $f \in \mathscr A$ whenever $f_n  \in \mathscr A (n = 1,2,3,...)$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$, then $\mathscr A$ is said to be *uniformly closed*.

My question is: why do we require the functions to be bounded in theorem 7.29? For example, in proving $$f_n +g_n \to f + n$$ whenever $f_n \to f, g_n \to g $ uniformly, we can just appeal to theorem 3.3a (which states $\lim_{n \to \infty} (s_n + t_n) = s + t$ whenever $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t$) to see that $f_n +g_n \to f + n$ uniformly. I don't see how boundedness is required here, nor anywhere else in proving the theorem.

So are the functions in $\mathscr A $ required to be bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we did not require boundedness, then $\mathscr{B}$ may not be closed under multiplication. In other words, it is false that if $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly and $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly, then $f_ng_n\rightarrow fg$ uniformly, unless we add an extra assumption like boundedness of at least one of the functions.

For example, on $E=\mathbb{R}$, consider $f_n(x)=x+1/n=g_n(x)$. Then, $f_n,g_n\rightarrow x$ uniformly, but the convergence of $f_ng_n$ to $x^2$ is not uniform.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. My reasoning was that Theorem 3.3 yields an $N$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$ for all $x \in E$, for each of the three operations, which would work for all $x$ due to uniform convergence, but when you look at the proof of multiplication (3.3b) there is a little more to the story. The $N$ is not guaranteed to work for all $x$. Thanks again, +1!